How to Resolve 'System.DllNotFoundException' Error on macOS When Running C# Application Developed on Windows?
I am encountering an issue when attempting to run a C# application on macOS that was originally developed and built on Windows. The application throws a 'System.DllNotFoundException' error related to platform-dependent native libraries.
Here are the details of my situation:
Background: I developed a C# application using Visual Studio on a Windows machine. The application relies on certain native libraries (like DLLs) that are specific to the Windows platform.
Problem: When I try to run the same application on macOS (using .NET Core or Mono), it fails with a 'System.DllNotFoundException' indicating that it cannot locate one or more required DLLs.
Error Message:
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'mylibrary.dll': The specified module could not be found. 
Research: I have researched this issue and understand that this error is typically caused by the absence or incompatibility of platform-specific native libraries (like DLLs) on macOS.
Attempted Solutions:

I have explored using Mono as a cross-platform runtime for my C# application, but the issue persists.
I have attempted to manually copy the required DLLs to the macOS environment, but this did not resolve the problem.

Question: How can I resolve the 'System.DllNotFoundException' error and ensure that my C# application runs smoothly on macOS? Is there a way to handle platform-specific dependencies effectively when developing cross-platform C# applications?
Any guidance, tips, or recommended practices for managing platform-dependent native libraries in cross-platform C# development (specifically targeting Windows and macOS) would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

In general, if the code depends on the native libraries, then you should build those libraries for all target platforms (so, Windows and Mac in your case). For more specific advice, it may be helpful to provide more details about which libraries you are talking about, and how those libraries are consumed: via nuget, p/invoke, etc. P.S. Don't use mono, it's almost dead, at least for macos. Use net8 instead.

Mono is cross plattform but for managed code. It does not know anything about native code. Either get rid of the native code because you solve the same in managed code or find an equivalent of the native code but made for macOS. A current mac isn't even the same CPU architecture anymore.

@Serg Thank you so much for your time and effort in responding, it's really helpful.

@Ralf Thank you so much for your time and effort in responding, it's really helpful too.
